# Determining the height of an mountain from two points of view.

Tags: trigonometry

From viewpoint A west of the mountain you can see the peak of the mountain from a angle of elevation 17.4 degrees. From viewpoint B which is 3000 meters to the north from viewpoint A you can see the peak of the mountain from the a angle of elevation of 14.5 degrees. What is the height of the mountain from sea level, when view points are 200 meter over the sea level.

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by drawing a picture and marking the pertinent variables in the picture.

Comment: I think that the info re viewpoint A is a red herring.  It provides no info, because the problem doesn't tell you how far away viewpoint A is.  This means that the solution is obtained solely by focusing on viewpoint B.

Comment: Viewpoint B is 3000 meters to the north from viewpoint A.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If the base of the mountain is $L$ and its top is $T$ and we have viewpoints $A$ and $B$ where $B$ is north of $A$,

we have $AL = h \cot 17.4^0, BL = h \cot 14.5^0 \,$ (where $LT = h = H - 200$ is its relative altitude to viewpoints $A$ and $B$, $H$ is altitude of its peak above the sea level).

Now using Pythagoras, $BL^2 - AL^2 = 3000^2$. Write $BL, AL$ in terms of $h$ and solve for $h$ and then add $200$ to get $H$.